# Different result in Node.js command and VS2015

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

I made a test with below node.js code in Node.js command and VS2015.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var ROOT_DIR = "Scripts/http/";
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var urlObj = url.parse(req.url, true, false);
    var reqPath = ROOT_DIR + urlObj.pathname;
    fs.readFile(ROOT_DIR + urlObj.pathname, function (err, data) {
        console.log(req.pathname);

        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}).listen(1111);
console.log('http server is open');
```

If I run this from VS2015, and then I enter "http://localhost:1111/hello.html", it output the content in hello.html.
But if I open run below command, it tells me 'http server is open', but if I enter above url, it tells me file not found.

```
C:\Users\xx>cd E:\xx\NodeJs
C:\Users\xx>node E:\xx\NodeJsProject\Scripts\http\http_server_static.js
```

I assume it is relative path issue, but I do not know details about it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(reqPath)` to your code to see what path you are constructing and it will probably show you your problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 they are the same "Scripts/http//hello.html"

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid path.  It's got a double `/` in it.  Plus if you're on Windows, I'm not sure whether it will handle the forward slash.

Comment: It is valid, I also tried var ROOT_DIR = "Scripts/http"; and it output Scripts/http/hello‌​.html. As my original post, it works under VS2015, it failed when I run from node.exe.

Comment: I'd suggest you probably have a problem with the relative path where the module directory is different in your two environments.  Change it to an absolute path and it should perform the same in both places.  You can call `path.resolve()` on your relative path and see what it comes out to be in both cases.  Probably different.

Comment: @jfriend00 perfect, I got the different absolute paths by path.resolve(). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer so you can wrap up this question...

I'd suggest you probably have a problem with the relative path where the module directory is different in your two environments. Change it to an absolute path and it should perform the same in both places. You can call `path.resolve()` on your relative path and see what it comes out to be in both cases. Probably different.